# How to check selected time is less than current or greater than current time using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

have used timepicker i got some time here i want to check that selected time is less than current time or gratter than current time.for example i have selected  11:00 AM ; var selectedtime='11:00 AM' how can i check 11:00 AM is less than current time or gratter than current time .i need to show alert i new to this technology help me out

```
$scope.date="Sat Dec 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
$scope.time = "11:00 AM";
```

for this particular date selected time is past or future i need to check
how can i get current time and check with selected time pls some one help me out

i have tried but i cant able to solve pls help me out

```
var now = new Date();
 var nowTime = new Date('1/1/1900 ' + now.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hour12: true
      }));
      console.log(nowTime);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily compare two `Date`s in javascript by using their timestamp values.

Call `.getTime()` on the date and it'll return the number of milliseconds passed since Jan 01 1970.

```
var now = new Date();
var d = new Date( ... ); // pass all the parameters you need to create the time
if (now.getTime() > d.getTime()) {
    // the date stored in `d` is in the past.
}
```

If you just need to compare the hours and minutes, you can call `.getHours()` and `.getMinutes()` for example. Then calculate the total number of minutes `d.getHours()*60+d.getMinutes()` then compare this value.

```
var now = new Date();
var d = new Date( ... );

var nowTime = now.getHours()*60+now.getMinutes();
var dateTime = d.getHours()*60+d.getMinutes();

// compare nowTime and dateTime
if (newTime > dateTime) {
    // ....
}
```

**After reading your comment.**

```
var getResult = function () {
    var now = new Date();
    var nowTime = new Date((now.getMonth()+1) + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes());
    var userTime = new Date((now.getMonth()+1) + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getFullYear() + " " + selectedTime);
    if (nowTime.getTime() > userTime.getTime()) {
        return "passed";
    }else if (nowTime.getTime() == userTime.getTime()) {
        return "present";
    }else {
        return "future";
    }
}
```

For angular version, check this http://plnkr.co/edit/UmpfBFR1zvL7qs9LpOjO?p=preview

Comment: can you pls add fiddle for me

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/8arMDKfinS5HGSJOKSiw?p=preview
just try to change `2015` to `2016` for example.

Comment: var selectedtime='11:00 AM' for this how can i check

Comment: Do you need to just compare the time? or also the date?

Comment: only time 
 
var selectedtime='11:00 AM'

Comment: if i select 11:00 AM .i need to check with current time past or future

Comment: for particular date how can i check that time is past or future $scope.date="Sat Dec 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
$scope.time = "11:00 AM";

Comment: i believe i covered most of the cases. Please do a little bit of research on your own and if you have a specific problem, ask another question. And if this post answers your question, consider upvoting and marking it as the answer.

Comment: i have tired to validat but i can't able to solve pls help me out

Comment: I dont know what exactly you need, can you provide an example with details?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are comparing this against the current day, you can build a new `Date()` object using today's info plus the time that is entered.

```
var time = "11:00 PM";
var dt = (now.getMonth()+1) + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getFullYear() + " " + time;
```

Then compare it against now:

```
var now = new Date();
var userval = new Date(dt);
if (now > userval) //do logic
```

[Here is an example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvd0wsyv/)

Comment: pls check your fiddle i didt understand

Comment: Enter a sample time in the field, like 11:10 AM or 4:23 PM, then click the button. Then it will tell you if the time you entered is less than or greater than the current time.

Comment: how can i convert this into angular